# How to know when all ajax calls are complete

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a table style page with rows. Each row has a checkbox. I can select all/many checkboxes and click "submit" and what is does is a Jquery ajax call for each row.

Basically I have a form for each row and I iterate over all the checked rows and submit that form which does the jquery ajax call.

So I have a button that does:

```
       $("input:checked").parent("form").submit();
```

Then each row has:

```
            <form name="MyForm<%=i%>" action="javascript:processRow(<%=i%>)" method="post" style="margin:0px;">
                <input type="checkbox" name="X" value="XChecked"/>
                <input type="hidden" id="XNumber<%=i%>" name="X<%=i%>" value="<%=XNumber%>"/>
                <input type="hidden" id="XId<%=i%>" name="XId<%=i%>" value="<%=XNumber%>"/>
                <input type="hidden" id="XAmt<%=i%>" name="XAmt<%=i%>" value="<%=XAmount%>"/>
                <input type="hidden" name="X" value="rXChecked"/>
            </form>
```

This form submits to processRow:

```
   function processRow(rowNum)
   {
        var Amount = $('#XAmt'+rowNum).val();
        var XId = $('#XId'+rowNum).val();
        var XNum = $('#OrderNumber'+rowNum).val();
        var queryString = "xAmt=" + "1.00" + "&xNumber=" + OrdNum + "&xId=" + xId;


        $('#coda_'+rowNum).removeClass("loader");
        $('#coda_'+rowNum).addClass("loading");


        $.ajax({
          url: "x.asp",
          cache: false,
          type:  "POST",
          data:  queryString,
          success: function(html){
            $('#result_'+rowNum).empty().append(html);
            $('#coda_'+rowNum).removeClass("loading");
            $('#coda_'+rowNum).addClass("loader");
          }
        });
   }
```

What I wanted to know is, from this is there a way I can tell if all my Ajax calls are complete. Reason being that want to enable/disable the submit button while all these calls are taking place.

Thanks and please note that I had to mangle my variable names due to the sensitivity of the application, so many of them may be duplicated.

Comment: While detecting when all ajax calls are complete has value for any design, I think a better overall solution is to submit multiple rows at once. Sending each row as a separate ajax post is going to be *really* hard on the system in some ways, and is not (in my opinion) the best design. I'll even go so far as to say that *I promise* that some day, if you stick to this design of one-ajax-call-per-row, you'll regret it.

Comment: Apart from the design problem pointed out by @ErikE, I'm surprised no one mentioned use of Promises to answer the original question.

Answer (score 150, accepted):

## The easy way

The easiest way is to use the [`.ajaxStop()` event handler](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStop/):

```
$(document).ajaxStop(function() {
  // place code to be executed on completion of last outstanding ajax call here
});
```

## The hard way

You can also manually detect if any ajax call is still active:

Create a variable containing number of active Ajax connections:

```
var activeAjaxConnections = 0;
```

just before opening new Ajax connection increment that variable

```
$.ajax({
  beforeSend: function(xhr) {
    activeAjaxConnections++;
  },
  url (...)
```

in `success` part check if that variable equals to zero (if so, the last connection has finished)

```
success: function(html){
  activeAjaxConnections--;
  $('#result_'+rowNum).empty().append(html);
  $('#coda_'+rowNum).removeClass("loading");
  $('#coda_'+rowNum).addClass("loader");
  if (0 == activeAjaxConnections) {
    // this was the last Ajax connection, do the thing
  }
},
error: function(xhr, errDesc, exception) {
  activeAjaxConnections--;
  if (0 == activeAjaxConnections) {
    // this was the last Ajax connection, do the thing
  }
}
```

As you can see, I've added also checking for return with error

Comment: how can you remove the ajaxStop handler again after it has been triggered?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3709597/wait-until-all-jquery-ajax-requests-are-done

Comment: Regarding 'The Hard way': There's no need to mantain a variable, Jquery already does this: $.active keeps the current number of active ajax calls

Comment: Is there any way to figure out which Ajax call it was, if there were multiple at the same time?

Comment: **The hard way** - this is safe? What if multiple success/error try `activeAjaxConnections--;` at the "same time"?

Answer (score 26):

A neat solution would be to use;

```
$("body").ajaxStop(function() {
    //Your code
});
```

For more information check out the jQuery .ajaxStop function at http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStop/

Answer (score 15):

Maybe:

```
jQuery.active == 0
```

Stolen from:

http://artsy.github.com/blog/2012/02/03/reliably-testing-asynchronous-ui-w-slash-rspec-and-capybara/

More info on StackOverflow:

[jQuery.active function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3148225/jquery-active-function)

Answer (score -4):

How about just simply use **if**?

```
success: function(html){
   if(html.success == true ){
            $('#result_'+rowNum).empty().append(html);
            $('#coda_'+rowNum).removeClass("loading");
            $('#coda_'+rowNum).addClass("loader");

          }
   }
```