# How to create event triggered after a some ajax calls completed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, event-handling, jquery-events

Please, help me create right event for my situation. I believe there is
*true way* to do it, without any counters (like this: [How to know when all ajax calls are complete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287188/how-to-know-when-all-ajax-calls-are-complete))

HTML:

```
<ul id="links">
    <li><a href="1.html">What is Yoda's first name?</a></li>
    <li><a href="2.html">Why does Padme die?</a></li>
    <li><a href="3.html">Who is Darth Rage?</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="content"></div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('#links a').each(function (index, el) {
    url = $(el).attr('href');
    $('<div class="article" />').appendTo('#content')
        .load(url, function(){
            filterOneArticle(this);
        });
});

// I want this function run after all articles will be loaded and filtered 
$.bind('yepAllArticlesHaveBeenLoaded', filterAllArticles);

filterAllArticles = function() {};
filterOneArticle = function(el) {};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If for whatever reason you don't want to use `ajaxStop` as Nick suggests (perhaps you're worried about other, unrelated ajax requests throwing you off), you can keep track of how many requests you've issued and check when each one succeeds/fails:

```
var requestCount = 0;
$('#links a').each(function (index, el) {
    url = $(el).attr('href');
    ++requestCount;
    $('<div class="article" />').appendTo('#content')
        .load(url, function(){
            filterOneArticle(this);
            --requestCount;
            if (requestCount == 0) {
                filterAllArticles();
            }
        });
});
```

That *looks* like it has a race condition *(What if the first article finishes loading before we've requested the second?)*, but it doesn't. JavaScript on browsers is single-threaded (barring the use of [web workers](http://www.w3.org/TR/workers/), which you have to do explicitly), and so we know we'll finish our loop initiating the requests before the first completion can come through.

Comment: Thanks a lot, now I am sure that there are no ways except counters.

Answer (score 1):

There an [`ajaxStop`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStop/) global event for this:

```
$(document).ajaxStop(filterAllArticles);
```

To unbind it so it doesn't run when the next ajax batch finishes (if there is any more ajax activity later), you can just call [`.unbind()`](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) in your `filterAllArticles` method:

```
$(document).unbind("ajaxStop", filterAllArticles);
```

Comment: Oh, thanks, it works great when there are only those ajax requests. But imagine that there are other requests, for example image galleries etc. `ajaxStop` will be fired only after **all** requests will be completed, but i need filter articles just after articles will be loaded.

Comment: @pereskokov -if you need it for just the articles and there are requests *at the same time*, then use a counter, you have no choice there.

Comment: Thanks a lot, now I am sure that there are no ways except counters.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery supports this behavior.
you can use jQuery to do the ajax call as show below. this method has two call back functions for success and for failure.

```
function loadData()
{
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        url: 'methodurl',
        success: methodSuccedded,
        error: methodFailure
    });
}

function methodSuccedded()
{}

function methodFailure()
{}
```

Comment: Thank you, but I know it. I meant other.