# JQuery ajaxComplete for all ajax in the page

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have Java Script file and i want do something after Ajax request/response is completed , so i found this function but i have multiple Ajax request/response and i want it to triger after all of theme completed.

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
  alert("Completed");
});

$(function main() {
  ...
  for (var i = 1; i < length; i++) {
    $.ajax({...});
});
```

How could i implement this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/287188/how-to-know-when-all-ajax-calls-are-complete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [ajaxStop](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStop/) instead of [ajaxComplete](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/) which fires on completion of each ajax request.

```
$( document ).ajaxStop(function() {

});
```

Answer (score 0):

By using ajaxsend and ajaxstop to easyly identify the started ans ended.

```
$("document").bind("ajaxSend", function() {
               console.log("********ajax call started ********");
  }).bind("ajaxStop", function() {
               console.log("********ajax call stoped ********");
  }).bind("ajaxError", function() {
               console.log("********ajax call error ********");
  });
```