# Check for ajax call completion

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm having a problem filling and accessing a global variable with ajax. I have the following code (stripped down a bit):

```
var answers;

$(document).ready(function() {

   showResults();

   console.log(answers);

}

function showResults(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "/wp-content/themes/hoekiesikeenschool/question-storage.php",
        data: { action: "get_results" },
        type: "post",
        dataType: "json"
    }).done(function (data) {

        answers = data.questionary; 
        return answers;

    }); 
}
```

My question is the following: When I log `answers` in the `done` function it gives me a nice array. That would mean the `array` variable is filled. But when I log it from `$(document).ready`, It returns an empty variable. This is probably because the AJAX call is asynchronous, and the log gets executed before the variable is filled.

However, I need to use that variable on another page, so I need to access it from the `$(document).ready` ... Any idea about how to check if the variable is filled? Or when the `showResults()` is completed? Thanks in advance for your help!

- Edit -

Thanks for your replies! But I'm still struggling with the following: As I understand, I can call another function from the ajax callback, and pass it the data. The thing is, I have to do a lot of different stuff with it after the call, and the only way I can get it to work now is by calling a function in the ajax callback, then calling another one from that one, etc...

So I end up wit `showResults();` in the `doc.ready`, which then executes a lot of functions that are all "linked" together. Is there anyway I can return the data to the variable, for use in other places? I hope I have made this clear, English is not my native language, sorry.

Comment: normally, things can be done with callbacks so you may not have to access the variable in doc.ready. Can you explain a bit about "use that variable on other pages" ?

Comment: Thanks for your reply! The problem I have is that I have to do a lot of things with the data I get from that ajax call. Maybe it is my lack of experience, but I can only get it working by calling another function from the callback, and then another one from that one, etc... I would like the ajax call to just fill a variable I can use in more place than one. I hope I made it clear, English is not my native language :( I've updated my question also.

Answer (score 1):

Execute the functionality that is dependent on the `answers` array after the AJAX call. Call your function from within `done(..)`

A very rough idea:

```
var answers;

function functionalityDependentOnAnswers() {
   //the code dependent on answers array.
}

$(document).ready(function() {

   showResults();

   //Move code here to functionalityDependentOnAnswers()
}

function showResults(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "/wp-content/themes/hoekiesikeenschool/question-storage.php",
        data: { action: "get_results" },
        type: "post",
        dataType: "json"
    }).done(function (data) {

        answers = data.questionary; 
        functionalityDependentOnAnswer();

    }); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `when` method provided by jQuery (look at [this SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3709597/wait-until-all-jquery-ajax-request-are-done)).

Or look [at this SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287188/how-to-know-when-all-ajax-calls-are-complete) where a similar situation is explained.

Answer (score 0):

Check the documentation for success: this will only be executed when successful callback is done.

```
var answers;

$(document).ready(function() {
   showResults();
}

function showResults(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "/wp-content/themes/hoekiesikeenschool/question-storage.php",
        data: { action: "get_results" },
        type: "post",
        dataType: "json"
    }).when(function (data) {
       console.log(answers);
        answers = data.questionary; 
        return answers;

    }); 
}
```

Comment: Because he want to check _when_ the call is finished and not _if_ the call is finished correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Idea: Have a hidden input field and add change listener to it.

```
<input type="hidden" id="answers_input" />
```

Now have a listener to this.

```
var answers;

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#answers_input').on('change', function() {
     // trigger your custom code
     console.log(answers);
    })
   showResults();

   console.log(answers);

}

function showResults(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "/wp-content/themes/hoekiesikeenschool/question-storage.php",
        data: { action: "get_results" },
        type: "post",
        dataType: "json"
    }).done(function (data) {
        answers = data.questionary; 
        $('#answers_input').val(answers);
    }); 
}
```

Solution is kinda like a hack, let me know if this works for you

Answer (score -1):

You're in the right way.

Do stuff with answers inside the DOM callback.

```
var answers;
$(document).ready(function() {
   showResults();
}

function showResults(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "/wp-content/themes/hoekiesikeenschool/question-storage.php",
        data: { action: "get_results" },
        type: "post",
        dataType: "json"
    }).done(function (data) {
        answers = data.questionary;
        console.log(answers);
        // Manage answers here
    }); 
}
```

Comment: `async:false` is a **very** bad advice!

Comment: As of version 1.8 using `asnyc: false` is deprecated, see http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: I agree with you guys, the best way is the first solution !
I removed the 2nd one, I knew it was a bad idea but not that is was deprecated, thanks !