# How to ensure that Backbone has rendered the page completely?

Tags: backbone.js, view, rendering, backbone-views, viewrendering

I work on a large enterprise application with BackboneJS. One page in the application is constructed using multiple sub-system calls via REsT. How do I make sure that, all the services required to load the page has been called and the templates are binding is completed?

For example, I have a `MasterView`, that takes care of the `collection.fetch()` of each child views, like this.

```
myApp.views.MasterView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function(params) {
        var self = this;
        this.collection.fetch({
            success: function(resp) {
                self.collection.bind("reset", self.render(), self);
            },
            error: function(xhr, xhrStatus) {
                // push error message, in case of fetch fails.
            }
        });
    },
    render: function() {
        var self = this;
        this.collection.each(function(model) {
            if (model.get('authorize') && model.get('status') === "success" && model.get('data').length > 0) {
                self.bindTemplate(model.get('data')[0]);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

I have a view set for the page, that takes care of rendering two other views CustomerInfo and CustomerAccounts. The view goes like this.

```
myApp.views.CustomerView = Backbone.View.extend({
        initialize: function() {
            var customerInfo = new myApp.collection.CustomerInfo();
            new myApp.views.CustomerInfo({el: $("#infoContainer"), collection: customerInfo});

            var customerAccount = new myApp.collection.CustomerAccount();
            new myApp.views.CustomerAccount({el: $("#accountContainer"), collection: customerAccount});
        }
});
```

And CustomerInfo and CustomerAccount views, looks like this,

```
myApp.views.CustomerInfo = myApp.views.MasterView.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        var self = this;
        myApp.views.MasterView.prototype.initialize.call(self, {
            qParam1: "qparam1",
            qParam2: "qparam2"
        });
    },
    render: function() {
        var self = this;
        self.template = _.template(myApp.Templates.get("customer-page/customer-info"));
        myApp.views.MasterView.prototype.render.apply(self);
    },
    bindTemplate: function(data) {
        var self = this;
        $(self.el).html(self.template({"info": data}));
    }
});
 
myApp.views.CustomerAccounts = myApp.views.MasterView.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        var self = this;
        myApp.views.MasterView.prototype.initialize.call(self, {
            qParam1: "qparam1"
        });
    },
    render: function() {
        var self = this;
        self.template = _.template(myApp.Templates.get("customer-page/customer-accounts"));
        myApp.views.MasterView.prototype.render.apply(self);
    },
    bindTemplate: function(data) {
        var self = this;
        $(self.el).html(self.template({"accounts": data}));
    }
});
```

I would like to know if there is any way to know from the `myApp.views.CustomerView` that the views `CustomerInfo` and `CustomerAccounts` has completed its rendering? The main problem I have here is the `CustomerInfo` view loads quickly but the `CustomerAccount` view takes some time to load. Hence I need to display the page on one shot, when both the views are ready on DOM.

Comment: Just an observation:  Your child views really should not have references to a parent view (i'd actually argue further that no view should have a reference to another view but that's another topic entirely)  I'd also recommend reading a few tutorials/examples on how to use Backbone more effectively; your views should be reacting to changes on models/collections; as it stands your views are doing WAY too much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After breaking my head for quite sometime, and searching on Google, I found [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287188/how-to-know-when-all-ajax-calls-are-complete).

So I made few changes to my MasterView and it was working and have solved the problem I had. The change I made in the MasterView is this

```
var activeConnections=0;

myApp.views.MasterView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function(params) {

        activeConnections++;

        var self = this;
        this.collection.fetch({
            success: function(resp) {

                activeConnections--;

                self.collection.bind("reset", self.render(), self);

                if(activeConnections===0){
                    // trigger the page has finished rendering
                }
            },
            error: function(xhr, xhrStatus) {
                // push error message, in case of fetch fails.
                if(activeConnections===0){
                    // trigger the page has finished rendering
                }
            }
        });
    },
    render: function() {
        var self = this;
        this.collection.each(function(model) {
            if (model.get('authorize') && model.get('status') === "success" && model.get('data').length > 0) {
                self.bindTemplate(model.get('data')[0]);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

**Thanks to all those who have helped me solve this.**

Answer (score 0):

When you instantiate your views add a listener to a view_ready event. When the view finishes fetching the data and rendering make it trigger it on itself 
At the end of the render method of the parent view

```
self.trigger('view_ready');
```

And on the *Main* view add something like :

```
this.listenTo(CustomerInfoView, 'view_ready', this.customer_info_ready);
this.listenTo(CustomerAccountsView, 'view_ready', this.customer_account_ready);
```

Then in your main view or main model add 2 properties : info_ready and customer_ready and initialize them to 0
Each time one of the 2 previously mentioned event is fired do something like the following :

```
customer_info_ready : function(){
    this.model.set('info_ready',true);
    if (this.model.get('account_ready') === true) {
         this.trigger('both_elements_ready'); 
     }
}
customer_account_ready : function(){
    this.model.set('account_ready',true);
    if (this.model.get('info_ready') === true) {
         this.trigger('both_elements_ready'); 
     }
}
```

Then add a listener to 'both_elements_ready' on your main view :

```
initialize: function() { 
 //your code
 this.on('both_elements_ready',this.page_ready); }
```

EDIT: Added info to make answer more relevant to question and more detailed.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but sorry that I could not complete my exact requirement while posting it for the first time. As per your suggestion, I would know when the `CustomerInfoView` and `CustomerAccountsView` are ready, but I need to know when both of them are ready.

Comment: Wow, this is even more convoluted than the question.  What's the point of using a framework if you plan on working around it and making it more complex than if there was no framework in the first place?

Comment: @RakanNimer: Your solution might be nice if there is just 2 views as mentioned in the question. But, what if there are even more views inside `myApp.views.CustomerView`

Comment: @Pierreten What do you suggest doing ?

Comment: Ok so pretty much using ChaplinJS will solve this in a very elegant manner !

Answer (score 0):

Edit: This answer is inspired by what I learned from a sample "*Brunch with Chaplin*" example [here](https://github.com/paulmillr/brunch-with-chaplin/tree/master/app). [Chaplin](http://chaplinjs.org/) is a framwork built on top of backbone.

---

Ok, so I'm going to suggest a coffeescript based solution (I just happen to have a solution in coffee :/ ! Try using [js2coffee](http://js2coffee.org/) if you want to convert back to js)

### The Master Class

The idea is to have a master class - not view -  that will hold the app in it's hand, instead of the master view.

```
module.exports = class Application
  initialize: (finished_init) =>
    @collection = new Collection()
    @main_view = new View()
    @collection.fetch(
      success: (collection) =>
        @main_view.collection = @collection
        finished_init()
    )
  render: (targetLocation, params) ->
    switch targetLocation
      when "main" then (
        @main_view.render()
      )
```

In the `initialize` method, we fetch the collection data. On success, the `finshed_init()` is called. You can replace it with `@render` (Btw, `@` == this :) )

### Initialization

Here's how I'd initialize my app:

```
$ ->
  app = new Application()

  app.initialize( ->
    #----------------------------------#
    # Create the router and its routes
    # This is called at the finished_init() of the Application class
    #----------------------------------#
    app_router = new Router
  )
```

### Running More than one `fetche` Asynchronously

You could have a function that monitors fetche's completion, **or** you could try using [async](https://github.com/caolan/async). It has a nice `` `parallel `` function that does just that.

```
@collection1 = new Collection()
@collection = new Collection()
@main_view1 = new View()
@main_view2 = new View()

async.parallel [ (callback) ->
  setTimeout (->
    @collection1.fetch(
      success: (collection) =>
        @main_view1.collection = @collection
        callback null, "one"
  ), 200
, (callback) ->
  setTimeout (->
    @collection2.fetch(
      success: (collection) =>
        @main_view2.collection = @collection
        callback null, "two"
  ), 100
 ], (err, results) ->
   if not err
    @render()  # Render what you want
```