# Waiting for all AJAX call than show dialog box

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, bootbox

I am working on a dynamic online form website. In the main form, I have multiple sub-forms which can be added and deleted dynamically.

```
<div class='subform'>
    //form fields 
    <input ...>
    ...
    <button class='subform_submit'>
</div>
```

For each subform, I bind an AJAX call on the subform's submit button like this:

```
$('#main').on('click', '.subform_submit', function(){
    // Get this subform's user input
    ...
    $.ajax({
        url: ..,
        type: ..,
        data: /* this subform's data */
    });
});
```

So in that page, I may have 0 to 10 subforms depending on the user's selection. 
I also have a main submit button on the bottom of the page, which can submit those subforms and the main form's data together.

```
$('#main').on('click', '#submit', function(e){
    $('.subform_submit').click(); // Submit each subform
    bootbox.confirm({ });
})
```

Once main submit button is clicked, I want to show a loading picture and then show a dialog box (I use `bootbox.confirm()` here) until all AJAX calls have completed.
This dialog box is telling user that whole form including sub-forms has been submitted. 
But the problem is that each AJAX call may take 2 seconds to complete and I don't know how may calls may be pending completion. How can I write this main submit button so that it will:

1. Show the loading image immediately, and
2. Hide the loading image and show the dialog box after all AJAX calls have completed?

Comment: Thanks for @Lewis  Best solution!

Answer (score 4):

Keep track of how many sub-forms there are;

```
$subFormsCount = $('.subform').length;
```

Keep track of how many forms have been submitted;

```
$submittedForms = 0;
```

Each time a form finishes submitting, add to the $submittedForms;

```
$.ajax({
  ..
  ..
  done: function(){
    $submittedForms++;
  }
})
```

Create a global timer to see if the number of submitted forms matches the total number of subforms. If true, hide the dialog box;

```
setInterval(function(){
  if($submittedForms == $subFormsCount){
   $('.dialog').show();
  }
}, 50ms)
```

## Edit

You could skip the global timer (as this will probably be a few milliseconds out) - include the check in your ajax.done instead;

```
$.ajax({
  ..
  ..
  done: function(){
    $submittedForms++;

    if($submittedForms == $subFormsCount){
     $('.dialog').show();
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: where should put dialog box code ?  If check in ajax.done, what if there is 0 subforms there and I still want to see dialog box?

Comment: @monknom I'm not sure what you're asking. I thought you wanted to show an image whilst subforms were submitting and the dialog box only when they had finished?

Comment: Sorry about my poor english,  image is for subforms submitting. but dialog box I want to tell people whole form has been submitted not only subform

Comment: Would the code above not work for this? Both $submittedForms and $subFormsCount would == 0 and therefore match, which should display the dialog? I'm not sure I fully understand your problem and perhaps someone else can help further.

Comment: @monknom Glad to hear it! Good luck with your project.

Answer (score 2):

You want to use [.done()](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/) in order to specify code that should wait until the AJAX asynchronous function completes.

```
 $.ajax({
     url:..,
     type: ..,
     data: /* this subform's data*/ })
     .done(function() {
         //Put code here
     });
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [.ajaxStop() event handler](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStop/) ?

```
$(document).ajaxStop(function() {
  // place code to be executed on completion of last outstanding ajax call here
});
```

also, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287188/how-to-know-when-all-ajax-calls-are-complete?answertab=votes#answer-287212)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have 9 subform and 1 main form.
Code for 8 subform will be same.

I use here async:false : Means next ajax will not be call until 1st one is not completed.

Sample Code Format :

```
var id = 5;
$.ajax({
    url:  ,
    type: 'POST',
    data: {'id':id},
    dataType: 'JSON',
    async: false,
    error : function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert('An error occurred!');
    },
    success : function(response){

    }
});
```

Just set variable in your last sub form that is 9th subform.

```
success : function(response){
        var counter = true;
    }

if(counter){
    /* Code to show dialog.*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$.when` to wait for each request to complete. Something like this should get you close. You'd basically want to store all the ajax requests in an array and pass that to `when` as the arguments.

```
$('#main').on('click', '.subform_submit', function () {

  var formRequests = $('.subform').map(function () {
    var $form = $(this);
    return $.ajax({
      url: '',
      data: $form.serialzeArray()
    });
  }).get();

  $.when.apply(undefined, formRequests).done(function () {
    console.log('All done!');
  });

});
```

Here goes a very similar little demo I just made up: https://jsfiddle.net/g9a06y4t/