# How to check if the current window is fully loaded?

Tags: javascript

Typically the method is to use:

```
    window.addEventListener('load', function() {

    });
```

Although this post a challenge if the plugin is loaded through ajax...since then the onload event has fired.

`document.readyState` is the closest thing I know to check if a page is loaded, yet this doesn't include fetched elements.

The link is for jQuery, and it doesn't include fetch.

Comment: I think you need to check each fetched element separately, and have one place that checks if all of them are loaded. I don't think there is any way around this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to know when all ajax calls are complete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287188/how-to-know-when-all-ajax-calls-are-complete)

Comment: @K.Kirsz The link is for jQuery, and it doesn't include fetch.