# How do I know when all AJAX calls from a particular functions are finished?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a function  which has many different function calls having many ajax calls inside. How do I know if all the ajax calls being triggered by `$("#save").click(...)` are completed ?

```
$("#save").click(function() {

    saveUpdateSeatDetails();
    markAbsent();

    setTimeout(function() {
        location.reload();
    }, 369);
});
```

I tried using `async: false`, but I get warring suggesting it's deprecated.

I also referred [How to know when all ajax calls are complete
?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287188/how-to-know-when-all-ajax-calls-are-complete/287212). However, this applies for the entire page. I want this to apply on a particular function only.

(Nothing ES6 )

Comment: Maybe you don't *have* to use Promises, but you *really should* if you want your code to be easily readable and maintainable. It's as simple as `Promise.all`, and if you want to serve to clients who might not support Promises, that's what polyfills are for.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pass in an array of Deferreds to $.when()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5627284/pass-in-an-array-of-deferreds-to-when)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should jQuery's [Deferred](https://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) (slightly different but mostly compatible with Promises), which is returned by `$.ajax` calls. I'm going to assume you're using `$.ajax` here since you used jQuery in your answer.

You'll need to update your functions to *return* the `$.ajax` calls:

```
function saveUpdateSeatDetails() {
    return $.ajax("http://example.com...");
}

function markAbsent() {
    return $.ajax("http://example.com...");
}
```

Then you can do:

```
$("#save").click(function() {
    $.when(saveUpdateSeatDetails(), markAbsent()).done(function() {
         alert("test")
    });
});
```

`$.when` waits for the Ajax requests to complete before executing the function.

Since this is part of jQuery 1.5+, any browser compatible with jQuery will be able to run this code (no ES6 needed).

Comment: Thank you so much. I will try this and let you know

Comment: Hello, I tried your solution. However there is one issue, the last function having ` location.reload();` doesn't get executed

Comment: @Richard-Ye can this be also used to return value from Ajax Function to a variable?

Comment: @therailslearner very sorry, there was an error in my original code, it has been fixed.

Comment: @vibs2006 the function you pass into `.done` will have the resolved Deferred values from the $.ajax calls passed into it as arguments. So the first result will be the first argument, the second will be the second argument, etc.