# How to loop with setTimeout even after a href redirect?

Tags: javascript, facebook, settimeout

I try to run a loop method on a web page (Facebook) like this:

```
function loopRefresh () {
  console.log("loop refresh method call");
  if (shallRefresh){
      setTimeout(function(){
        loopRefresh()
        //Do something here
      }, 5000);
  } else {
      setTimeout(function(){
        loopRefresh()
        //Do something different here
      }, 5000);
  }
}
```

Now so far so good, everything works and the method is called every 5th second. The problem is that when the user clicks the home button:
[image: Facebook Home Button Code]

the page gets reloaded because of the anchor tag and the href, even though it does not refer to a new page.
This breaks the loop.

I already added this function as onclick event to the Home Button:

```
function homeRefresh() {
  shallRefresh = true;
//setTimeout(function(){
//  Do the same thing here as in the true case in the loopRefresh method
// }, 2000);
}
```

I originally just wanted to make the setTimeout call in here, so that the callback function gets executed after the user clicked the button, without the loopRefresh method. But I thought I could solve the problem by passing the variable, which also doesn't work.

Comment: Based on that screenshot, you are referencing a fully qualified url. When clicked by a user, it will refresh the page...

Comment: okay, so is there like an "onrefresh" event that I can use to trigger a function call after that refresh?

Answer (score 1):

Use **event.preventDefault()** on function starting. like,

```
function homeRefresh() {
  event.preventDefault(); // here..

  shallRefresh = true;
  //setTimeout(function(){
  //  Do the same thing here as in the true case in the loopRefresh method
  // }, 2000);
}
```

event.preventDefault() will prevent the default action of the hyperlink.

> NOTE: You cannot continue a javascript function after a page reload.

Comment: thanks a lot! so the way to execute a function after that realod would be <body onload="function()">, yes? That is the only way?

Comment: basically it is not possible. when a page is reloaded, its entire asset files are also reloaded. so is the javascript. browser will stop everything (every running functions, loops, watchers, etc.) when a page is navigated away. but nothing is impossible. you can set a unique local storage variable before page reload and cross verify it after reload.

Comment: onload will get executed after the page load. not reload.

Comment: Okay thanks for the input about the unique local storage variables, will look into this. But I think the page is not fully reloaded. I load the code via an Add-On for Firefox and when I refresh the page with ctrl + r my code is reloaded and the loopRefresh function runs again. If I click on the button it is not. There has to be two different reloads, lol.

Comment: i think you are talking about ajax reloads. specific areas of a website can be changed by using ajax methods.

Comment: I'm not familiar with these, how can I make sure that the loop method is called after one of  these ajax reloads is executed, or is that also not possible?

Comment: ajax requests have callbacks. but finding the function which performs the request from code like Facebook's is a headache. or you can use jquery to catch all ajax requests in a page. https://stackoverflow.com/a/287212/2249193 
are you developing an extension?

Comment: yes I do. Indeed it would be, but the way to search for the right ajax call also doesn't sound easy and I don't wanna screw up any native Facebook code...I just need to make sure after someone clicked the Home button and some part of the page is reloaded that I can trigger my function. I think I might use MutationObservers and just look up the value of my variable that I can set when the Home Button was clicked.

Comment: Tried that, but without using setTimeout I cannot trigger something after that reload....even with the MutationObserver it doesn't work...is there any event that I can observe?

Comment: don’t know ☹️ I'm helpless.