# DOM Event when all initial Javascript executed

Tags: javascript

Is there a DOM event that fires when (in addition to all of the DOM elements being loaded including images, stylesheets etc.) some initial Javascript finishes fetching data and then updates DOM?

The use case is in a closed system where I am calling `window.print()` to open a print dialog, but only once full page is loaded and all Javascript returns its data.

I have tried using `MutationObserver`, but it fires multiple times and I need it to fire only once when all of the loading is finished.

I have a workaround ready (by creating a Custom Event and firing it when scripts finish), but I am wondering if there is some kind of built-in event that is capable of this.

Comment: I don't believe so, and if there was would it be a benefit in your case, since you have JavaScript waiting for the "all JavaScript has finished" event which wouldn't fire because some of your JavaScript is waiting for that event? To be clear, I think - though I'd be interested in being proven wrong - that the`customEvent` is your best bet.

Comment: If you are specifically waiting for all ```ajax``` events to be completed, look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287188/how-to-know-when-all-ajax-calls-are-complete

Comment: @prettyInPink Not an `ajax` case here, but that is exactly what I'm looking for.